# Subsetting data, finding MAX, MIN, Mean and plotting it

Tags: r

So I have data in as follows:

```
id expressions mode 
1      22       0
2      24       0
3      23       0
4      5        1
5      56       1
6      42       1
7      32       0
8      21       0
9      11       1
10     72       1
```

So I will get A new table according to the previous question asked:

```
id     max     mean    min    mode 
1       24      23      22      0
2       56      51      5       1
3       32      26      21      0
4       72      41      11      1
```

So basically roll apply function with variable window which considers one window when toggle happens , which is in the output , I have shown.

Comment: I think the second value of `mean` should be 34 i.e. `mean(c(5, 56, 42))#
[1] 34.33333`

Comment: Thanks a lot Jaap for the edit .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table` to do a group by operation based on the run-length-id of 'mode' and get the `max/mean/min/mode` of 'expressions'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(Max = max(expressions), Mean = round(mean(expressions)),
    Min = min(expressions)), .(id = rleid(mode), mode)]
#    id mode Max Mean Min
#1:  1    0  24   23  22
#2:  2    1  56   34   5
#3:  3    0  32   26  21
#4:  4    1  72   42  11
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(id = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(mode) != 0)), mode) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(expressions), funs(max, mean= round(mean(.)), min))
#      id  mode   max  mean   min
#   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     0    24    23    22
#2     2     1    56    34     5
#3     3     0    32    26    21
#4     4     1    72    42    11
```

Comment: sorry for the delayed response, but thanks a lot man ,it worked perfectly. Cheers. @Akrun