# logical vector split in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a logical vector:

```
FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I want to split this vector into three groups: the first one (3 first `FALSE`) the second one (2 `TRUE`) and the last one (two last `FALSE`).
How can I do the loop to split the vector?

Comment: `split(x, cumsum(c(0,diff(x)!=0)))` Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661269/increment-by-1-for-every-change-in-column-in-r).

Comment: `rleid(x)` in `data.table` too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increment by 1 for every change in column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661269/increment-by-1-for-every-change-in-column-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that assumes you want to define a group variable along side the logical vector in a data frame.

```
library(dplyr)

YourLogicalVector <- rep(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), c(3, 2, 4))

data.frame(X = YourLogicalVector) %>%
  mutate(Boundary = X != lag(X, default = FALSE),
         Group = cumsum(Boundary))
```