# Column of sequence with repeated elements based on column with dates

Tags: r, dataframe, seq, rep

Consider a data frame ordered by a column with dates:

```
df=data.frame(event=1:12,
              subject=rep("M325",12),
              date=c(rep("2017-11-01",4),rep("2017-11-14",8)))
```

What I want is to create a fourth column with a sequence from 1 to the next unique date, with every element in the sequence repeated every i-*th* date. For example:

```
   event subject       date num
1      1    M325 2017-11-01   1
2      2    M325 2017-11-01   1
3      3    M325 2017-11-01   1
4      4    M325 2017-11-01   1
5      5    M325 2017-11-14   2
6      6    M325 2017-11-14   2
7      7    M325 2017-11-14   2
8      8    M325 2017-11-14   2
9      9    M325 2017-11-14   2
10    10    M325 2017-11-14   2
11    11    M325 2017-11-14   2
12    12    M325 2017-11-14   2
```

Any advice to get this result for *n* dates will be very appreciated.

Comment: Try `df$num <- cumsum(!duplicated(df$date))`  if it is ordered, and if it is based on the blocks of 'date' which can occur later again and then the `num` also changes, `setDT(df)[, num := rleid(date)]`

Comment: @akrun Wow, that was fast! The first worked perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the answer by @akrun

```
df$num <-cumsum(!duplicated(df$date))
```

Or using `data.table:`

```
setDT(df)[, num := rleid(date)]
```

Are faster, [this answer using rle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29661794/8594289) can actually solve my problem.