# Multiple Conditional Cumulative Sum in R

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum

This is my data frame as given below

```
rd <- data.frame(
    Customer = rep("A",15),                 
    date_num = c(3,3,9,11,14,14,15,16,17,20,21,27,28,29,31),                  
    exp_cumsum_col = c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7))
```

I am trying to get column 3 (`exp_cumsum_col`), but am unable to get the correct values after trying many times. This is the code I used:

```
rd<-as.data.frame(rd %>%
    group_by(customer) %>%                
    mutate(exp_cumsum_col = cumsum(row_number(ifelse(date_num[i]==date_num[i+1],1)))))
```

If my `date_num` is continuous, then I am treating that entire series as a one number, and if there is any break in my `date_num`, then I am increasing `exp_cumsum_col` by 1 ..... `exp_cumsum_col` would start at 1.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your expected output.

Comment: Expected output is 3rd column (exp_cumsum_col)

Comment: Could be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661269/increment-by-1-for-every-change-in-column

Answer (score 2):

We can take the differece of adjacent elements, check if it is greater than 1 and get the `cumsum`

```
rd %>% 
   group_by(Customer) %>%
   mutate(newexp_col = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(date_num) > 1)))
#    Customer date_num exp_cumsum_col newexp_col
#1         A        3              1          1
#2         A        3              1          1
#3         A        9              2          2
#4         A       11              3          3
#5         A       14              4          4
#6         A       14              4          4
#7         A       15              4          4
#8         A       16              4          4
#9         A       17              4          4
#10        A       20              5          5
#11        A       21              5          5
#12        A       27              6          6
#13        A       28              6          6
#14        A       29              6          6
#15        A       31              7          7
```

Comment: If i use this for multiple customers , then it does not provide complete answer....could you provide some inputs for group by customers ?

Comment: @YogeshKumar You just need `group_by(Customer)` before the mutate..  Updated

Comment: Once you don't need the groups use `ungroup()`. (filter and mutate operations are faster on ungrouped data frames, at least on dplyr 0.7.4)