# put sequence numbers in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like a bellow

```
date    input   
....     org
....     Min 1
....     Min 1
....     Min 1
....     Min 2
....     Min 2
....     Min 3
....     org
....     org
....     Min 1
....     Min 2
....     Min 2
....     Min 3
....     Min 3
....     Min 4
```

And I want to add another column with a classification of the input like bellow

```
date    input      Number_input
....     org           1
....     Min 1         2
....     Min 1         2
....     Min 1         2
....     Min 2         3
....     Min 2         3
....     Min 3         4
....     org           5
....     org           5
....     Min 1         6
....     Min 2         7
....     Min 2         7
....     Min 3         8
....     Min 3         8
....     Min 4         9
```

Can help me? ;-)

Comment: Can you please make your data reproducible?

Comment: please share a reproducible example

Comment: Hi Abdel, it's difficult to know exactly what you're looking for. Perhaps you could reformat your examples, or better yet, provide the output of `dput()`? You can edit your question and paste the output. You can surround it with three backticks (```) for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info.

Comment: thanks, @lan Campbell for formating my post to the correct format, i think now it's more clear what I'm searching to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for `rleid()` from `data.table`:

```
df$Number_input <- data.table::rleid(df$input)
df

   data input Number_input
1    ….   org            1
2    …. Min 1            2
3    …. Min 1            2
4    …. Min 1            2
5    …. Min 2            3
6    …. Min 2            3
7    …. Min 3            4
8    ….   org            5
9    ….   org            5
10   …. Min 1            6
11   …. Min 2            7
12   …. Min 2            7
13   …. Min 3            8
14   …. Min 3            8
15   …. Min 4            9
```

Reproducible data

```
df <- data.frame(
  data = "….",
  input = c(
    "org", "Min 1", "Min 1", "Min 1", "Min 2", "Min 2", "Min 3", 
    "org", "org", "Min 1", "Min 2", "Min 2", "Min 3", "Min 3", "Min 4"
  )
)
```

Comment: thanks @sindri_baldur it's more simple with rleid ;-)

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Number_input = rle(input)$lengths %>% 
  {rep(seq(length(.)), .)})
```

Which gives:

```
   date  input input_number
   <chr> <chr>        <int>
 1 ….    org              1
 2 ….    Min 1            2
 3 ….    Min 1            2
 4 ….    Min 1            2
 5 ….    Min 2            3
 6 ….    Min 2            3
 7 ….    Min 3            4
 8 ….    org              5
 9 ….    org              5
10 ….    Min 1            6
11 ….    Min 2            7
12 ….    Min 2            7
13 ….    Min 3            8
14 ….    Min 3            8
15 ….    Min 4            9
```

dput:

```
structure(list(date = c("….", "….", "….", "….", "….", "….", "….", 
"….", "….", "….", "….", "….", "….", "….", "…."), input = c("org", 
"Min 1", "Min 1", "Min 1", "Min 2", "Min 2", "Min 3", "org", 
"org", "Min 1", "Min 2", "Min 2", "Min 3", "Min 3", "Min 4")), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Found the solution from @mpettis here: [Increment by 1 for every change in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661269/increment-by-1-for-every-change-in-column)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `diff` by using the numbers from a cast to `factor` and create the `cumsum`:

```
cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(unclass(factor(x$input)))!=0))
# [1] 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 8 9
```

or you compare the shifted vectors of euqality:

```
cumsum(c(TRUE, x$input[-1] != x$input[-nrow(x)]))
# [1] 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 8 9
```

or using `xtfrm` instead of `factor`

```
cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(xtfrm(x$input))!=0))
# [1] 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 8 9
```